# How can I get the value of the 'Array of JTextField' and store it in an Array Integer?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield

I have two arrays of `JTextField` and I want to store it into another array.

```
JTextField[] proText, atText; 


int[] burst, arrive;
```

I have tried the usual way of the passing the value of the array

```
while(true){
    if(atText[lowerBound].getText() != " " && proText[lowerBound].getText() != " "){
        bt = proText[lowerBound].getText();
        at = atText[lowerBound].getText();
        burst[lowerBound] = Integer.parseInt(bt);
        arrive[lowerBound] =Integer.parseInt(at);
        break;
    }else 
        break;
}
```

***the 'lowerBound' is being incremented when I click the button.

BTW this is dynamic, in which it adds another text field when I am clicking the button. The problem here is that only the last number is displayed and the rest are zero. Is there another way to get the value of a text field?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do? but first if you're comparing strings use equals and not ==

Comment: it will check if the textfield is null or not

Comment: if you want to check for null, use getText() == null, if you want to check for blank use getText().trim().isEmpty() but don't use == for strings

Comment: yes, thank for that. But is there still another way to get the value of JTextField and store it in int array?

Comment: Using getText is the way to get the text of JTextField. What exactly the while loop do ?

Comment: because the JTextField is an array, it is incharge of iterating for the next Jtextfield

Comment: I understand that you want to save each jtextfield text in the array, but when the loop are executed, and what's the point of a loop if you break from it after only one iteration ?? just post all of your code and add some clarifications

Comment: I Have changed some somethings, you can take a look if you like. this is the link : https://justpaste.it/4jew2

Comment: Just to be sure, you create text fields dynamically and you want to store each value in an array. What's the total number of dynamic fields you'll create ??

Comment: That depends on the user, as long as they click the add button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your code, the problem is simple, each time you hit one of the buttons, you re-init your arrays. Of cours the previous values will be lost.

A quick fix is to copy the values first and then store the new value in your `actionPerformed` method

```
int[] atTemp = new int[arrsize];
int[] btTemp = new int[arrsize];
for (int i = 0; i < arrsize - 1; i++) {
    atTemp[i] = at[i];
    btTemp[i] = bt[i];
}
at = atTemp;
bt = btTemp;
```

But if you don't know the size of your arrays then use `ArrayList`, then you don't have to re-init your array each time you hit the buttons.

Comment: Hii Thank You for your help, i got the answer to my problem. Even though it took me awhile to realize that there is a more efficient way to solve. Thank you. Thank you for mentioning arraylist that really helped alot.